# Regular expression parse inside quotes separated by commas

Tags: php, regex

I have a file that's formatted like this:

```
"A","B","C - "G"","D,F",5
```

This is the match I'm trying to get:

```
|A|B|C - "G"|D,F|5|
```

I need to get content inside quotation marks, this is the expression that I'm using: `(?:"([^,]*)")`. But the problem occurs when there's comma inside quotes. Is it possible to achieve this with regex or I should just change the original string to something like this:

```
"A"@"B"@"C - "G""@"D,F"
```

Comment: It would be better to have double quotes inside double quotes escaped: `"A", "B", "C - \"G\"", "D,F"`

Comment: How are you generating the file/string in the first place?  You mentioned that you can change the delimiter, does this mean you're printing out lines by joining an array?

Comment: I'm not generating the string (reading it from a file) but I can do this: `str_replace("\",\"", "@")`

Comment: You may want to replace `^\h*"|"\h*$|", "` with `|`. Live demo https://regex101.com/r/Be9vvd/1

Comment: @revo Yeah that's better than str_replace. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
(?|"((?:(?!",).)*)"|\h*([^,"]+))
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/cMa1Z9/3)

PHP code:

```
$str = <<<_
"A", "B", "C - "G"", "D, F", 5
_;
preg_match_all('~(?|"((?:(?!",).)*)"|\h*([^,"]+))~', $str, $matches);
echo "|" . implode("|", array_filter($matches[1], 'trim')) . "|";
```

Comment: I just checked and delimiter is always only `,` without spaces

Comment: You are continuously changing your requirements.

Comment: I know and I'm sorry, I'm going through a lot of files that I didn't or will generate and it's a mess...

Comment: Fails on `1,"A",5,A,"D,8"`, so I modified it to work to this `(?|"((?:(?!",).)*)"|([^,]*))`. Thank you!

Comment: I assume a digit or a string inside quotes. Otherwise you may face many false positives and unexpected output since the rule is no rule.

Comment: The file structure is silly. It like`X,Y,"Z"` and since `Z` is in quotes then `Z` could be `lore, ipsum "dolem"` and I need to parse it as `|lore, ipsum "dolem"|`. So in the end it would be `|X|Y|lore, ipsum "dolem"|`

Answer (score 0):

```
"([^,]*|([^,"]*,?)*)"|([0-9]+)
```

will match something like:

```
"A", "B", "C - "D"", "E,F", "G,H,I", 5, 6, 2135231
```

I've updated the answer since you've changed the requirements.

[Live Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3ygZLn/4)

Comment: That's it! Thanks

Comment: @John This fails on `"A", "B", "C - "G"", "D,F", "F,Z,K"` https://regex101.com/r/3ygZLn/2

Comment: Ugh, I think that I'm going to have to use replace and then string substring on the split character... Too bad there isn't a regrex solution.

Comment: What about this? "([^,]*|([^,"]*,?)*)"

Comment: Fixed the answer to accomodate revo's example

Comment: Now it fails on `"A", "B", "C - "G"", "D,F,"G"F,Z,K"`

Comment: If OP needs that specific string to match, then I can update the answer...